# Dynamic Security PPS 2010 for filters using SSAS

Tags: performancepoint

I am new to SSAS and PPS implementation. And I was asked to implement dynamic security for PPS dashboard filters.

The requirement is as follows

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|             |                               USER 1                                 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|             |      COUNTRY FILTER                 |    YEAR FILTER                 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Dashboard 1 | has Access to USA, Canada and Italy | Has Access to 2009, 2010       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Dashboard 2 |  Has Access to India, UK and USA    | Has access to 2009, 2011, 2012 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In the above table the same "User 1" having different set of items for same filter (either Country/Year) based on dashboard.

I implemented security as mentioned in the below link

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1844/sql-server-analysis-services-ssas-dimension-security-stored-procedures/

But by following the link i am able to send only logged in user id to SSAS but not the dashboard name or id from which the user is accessing the filter.

So please help me out to achieve my requirement using PPS and SSAS. Please suggest if you have any alternate way to complete my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

If you truly want security to be dynamic and data-driven, the best approach is to use a user dimension in your dimensional model which you can use to slice your fact table.  With PerformancePoint you can filter results by adding an MDX filter to each dashboard, which filters the reports by the current user (if you like you can also allow the user to select other users that report to the current user, etc.)  Note that you cannot use a shared service account in the connection because SSAS will need to be able to access the identity of the currently logged in user.